# json data parsing using retrofit and rxjava2 data display in Textview and TableLayout

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2, android-tablelayout

JSON Data Parsing Using Retofit2 and Rxjava2. This Data get In ArrayList successfully. its ArrayList Size is Nine but its display only two Record in Table. After Two Record its Kotlin.NullPointerException.

JSON Data:

```
 {"success":1,"salesGst":[{"Cmp_Name":"ABC","GSTIN":"AAAA","FirmName":"SALES GJ","ChallanNo":"1","ChallanDate":"2019-03-15 00:00:00","ChallanAmount":"2778.75","TaxTotal":"2778.75","InvoiceType":"Retail Invoice","CGSTTotal":"0.0","PartyGST":"CDE","SGSTTotal":"0.0","IGSTTotal":"0.0"},{"Cmp_Name":"ABC","GSTIN":"AAAA","FirmName":"SALES GJ","ChallanNo":"1","ChallanDate":"2019-03-13 00:00:00","ChallanAmount":"2203.0","TaxTotal":"2118.5","InvoiceType":"Tax Invoice","CGSTTotal":"52.96","PartyGST":"CDE","SGSTTotal":"52.96","IGSTTotal":"0.0"},{"Cmp_Name":"ABC","GSTIN":"AAAA","FirmName":"VIKAS","ChallanNo":"2","ChallanDate":"2019-03-16 00:00:00","ChallanAmount":"6975.0","TaxTotal":"6975.0","InvoiceType":"Retail Invoice","CGSTTotal":"0.0","PartyGST":null,"SGSTTotal":"0.0","IGSTTotal":"0.0"},{"Cmp_Name":"ABC","GSTIN":"AAAA","FirmName":"SALES MH","ChallanNo":"2","ChallanDate":"2019-03-13 00:00:00","ChallanAmount":"420.0","TaxTotal":"403.75","InvoiceType":"Tax Invoice","CGSTTotal":"0.0","PartyGST":"ABC","SGSTTotal":"0.0","IGSTTotal":"20.19"},{"Cmp_Name":"ABC","GSTIN":"AAAA","FirmName":"SALES GJ","ChallanNo":"3","ChallanDate":"2019-03-14 00:00:00","ChallanAmount":"4788.0","TaxTotal":"4560.0","InvoiceType":"Tax Invoice","CGSTTotal":"114.0","PartyGST":"CDE","SGSTTotal":"114.0","IGSTTotal":"0.0"},{"Cmp_Name":"ABC","GSTIN":"AAAA","FirmName":"SALES GJ","ChallanNo":"4","ChallanDate":"2019-03-15 00:00:00","ChallanAmount":"241.9","TaxTotal":"230.38","InvoiceType":"Tax Invoice","CGSTTotal":"5.76","PartyGST":"CDE","SGSTTotal":"5.76","IGSTTotal":"0.0"},{"Cmp_Name":"ABC","GSTIN":"AAAA","FirmName":"SALES GJ","ChallanNo":"5","ChallanDate":"2019-03-15 00:00:00","ChallanAmount":"5563.68","TaxTotal":"5101.5","InvoiceType":"Tax Invoice","CGSTTotal":"231.28","PartyGST":"CDE","SGSTTotal":"231.28","IGSTTotal":"0.0"},{"Cmp_Name":"ABC","GSTIN":"AAAA","FirmName":"SALES GJ","ChallanNo":"6","ChallanDate":"2019-03-16 00:00:00","ChallanAmount":"13238.0","TaxTotal":"12459.25","InvoiceType":"Tax Invoice","CGSTTotal":"389.29","PartyGST":"CDE","SGSTTotal":"389.29","IGSTTotal":"0.0"},{"Cmp_Name":"ABC","GSTIN":"AAAA","FirmName":"SALES MH","ChallanNo":"7","ChallanDate":"2019-03-16 00:00:00","ChallanAmount":"2074.0","TaxTotal":"1975.0","InvoiceType":"Tax Invoice","CGSTTotal":"0.0","PartyGST":"ABC","SGSTTotal":"0.0","IGSTTotal":"98.75"}]}
```

Please Guide Me,After Getting How to Show in TableLayout.

In ArrayList Nine Record but in Table show only Two Record another seven record is not display. in third record taxtotal give kotlin.nullpointerException. what missing?

```
 private fun displaySalesGSTData(salesGSt : List<SalesGST>) {

        salesGST = SalesGST()
        tvSalesCompanyName.setText(salesGSt.get(1).Cmp_Name)
        tvGSTIN.setText(salesGSt.get(1).GSTIN)


        val rowHeader = TableRow(this@Sales)
        rowHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c0c0c0"))
        rowHeader.setLayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
        val headerText = arrayOf<String>("Sr.No.", "Invoice Type", "Bill No.", "Bill Date", "Firm Name", "GST NO","TAX Total","CGST","SGST","IGST","Net Amount")
        for (c in headerText)
        {
            val tv = TextView(this@Sales)
            tv.setLayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
           // tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header)
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"))
            tv.setTextSize(18F)
            tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5)
            tv.setText(c)
            rowHeader.addView(tv)
        }
        tableMarks.addView(rowHeader)

        for (j in 0 until salesGSt.size)
        {
            /*val jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j)
            val date = jsonObject1.getString("ExamDate")
            val inputFormatter1 = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            val date1 = inputFormatter1.parse(date)
            val outputFormatter1 = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
            ExamDate = outputFormatter1.format(date1)*/
            /* String replaceDate = date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
           Long getDate = Long.valueOf(replaceDate);
           ExamDate = dateFormat.format(getDate);*/
            /*Subject = jsonObject1.getString("subject")
            ExamName = jsonObject1.getString("ExamName")
            TotalMark = jsonObject1.getLong("TotalMarks")
            PassingMark = jsonObject1.getLong("PassingMarks")
            Mark = jsonObject1.getLong("Marks")*/

            var fName : String = salesGSt.get(j).FirmName!!
            var invoice : String = salesGSt.get(j).InvoiceType!!
            var bill_no : String = salesGSt.get(j).ChallanNo!!
            var bill_date : String = salesGSt.get(j).ChallanDate!!
            var gst_no : String = salesGSt.get(j).PartyGST!!
            var tax_total : Double = salesGSt.get(j).TaxTotal!!.toDouble()
            var cgst : String = salesGSt.get(j).CGSTTotal!!
            var igst : String = salesGSt.get(j).IGSTTotal!!
            var sgst : String = salesGSt.get(j).SGSTTotal!!
            var net_amount : String = salesGSt.get(j).ChallanAmount!!

            var sr : Int = j + 1
            // dara rows
            val row = TableRow(this@Sales)
            row.setLayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
            val colText = arrayOf<String>(sr.toString(),(invoice), bill_no, bill_date, fName, gst_no, tax_total.toString(),cgst,sgst,igst,net_amount)
            for (text in colText)
            {
                val tv = TextView(this@Sales)
                tv.setLayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
               // tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_shape)
                tv.setTextSize(18F)
                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"))
                tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5)
                tv.setText(text)
                row.addView(tv)
            }
            tableMarks.addView(row)
        }



    }
```

Comment: Please read the guide about ["how to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And add some useful code to help us understand where your problem could be

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd item, `salesGst[2]`, is `"PartyGST": null`. Your json deserializer library won't handle non-null fields as it's written in Java. I assume you have a data class where `PartGST` is defined as non-null, yet the deserializer will still parse it as null. Therefore, when you access `PartyGST` then you will receive a `NullPointerException` because Kotlin is expecting it to be non-null. This is a good article, which explains in more detail:

[I've trusted you! You promised no null pointer exceptions!](https://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2018-05-25-kotlin-gson-nullability.html)

A solution to this would be to have two models. The DTO (for JSON response) where all fields are optional and your internal model (used by your app), where you define which fields you want to be optional. Then you can have a mapper to handle the case where a field is null in the DTO, but non-null in your internal model:

```
// Models for your API response
data class SalesGstsDTO(val gsts: List<GstDTO>)
data class GstDTO(val name: String?, val surname: String?)

// Internal models used by your app
data class SalesGsts(val gsts: List<Gst>)
data class Gst(val name: String, val surname: String?)

class SalesGstDTOMapper {

    fun mapToSalesGsts(salesGstsDTO: SalesGstsDTO): SalesGsts {
        val gsts = mutableListOf<Gst>()
        salesGstsDTO.gsts.map {
            val name = it.name ?: return@map // Skips this item. You could handle this how you wish
            val surname = it.surname
            val gst = Gst(name, surname)
            gsts.add(gst)
        }
        return SalesGsts(gsts)
    }
```

}

This also allows you to decouple your app from the JSON response.